# Did anyone else notice, that users apply "pretty girl" avatars trying to enhance their chances to get answered?

Tags: discussion

I have seen such avatars used by particularly low rep users a lot

[image]

Seems like these are nerds, and they've well conceived how to attract attention from other nerds.

I don't actually know what I really want to ask about such things here. But though I'm gonna try

- How should we handle that (out of band from the actual questions
  quality). I'm tempted to leave notes (comments) about this, but
  they'll likely be removed because of being `not constructive` or
  other reasons legally claiming *gender concerns*.

While I don't want to prevent pretty (or any) girls from programming, I doubt most of them appearing in avatars, are real  girls at all.

I have an avatar picture showing a pretty girl myself, and of course I'm not looking like this. May be my question falls under that motto she gives along ;-) ...

Comment: As long as it's not profane, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Unihedron It's profane, that's what's wrong with it IMHO.

Comment: There used to be a "report this profile" option under users' profiles for this, but now removed.

Comment: I think this could well be an indicator for _"sock puppets"_.

Comment: I suspect its more spammers using stock images.

Comment: Same kind of approach as using pretty Greek letters.

Comment: @HansPassant Aww, that's unfair. I'm well giving some explanations in my profile text.

Comment: On the main page, you don't even see the avatar before you decide to take on a question in the list.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Ehh what? Depends on how you're working with SO, doesn't it?

Comment: Somehow I'm glad this post received that many downvotes. But it pretty much shows what _gender concerned misconceptions_ could mean on SO (or MSO) :P ...

Answer (score 24):

Pretty girls can be nerds too. We can't know for certain (in most cases) if an account's avatar is a real picture of the actual person behind the account, so we can't police this (and shouldn't bother to).

**Please do not comment on a post regarding someone's avatar.** Those would definitely be removed as not constructive. Comments about someone's avatar would be pointless *at best*, and harassing at worst, so please just don't do it.

You can flag a post for moderator attention regarding someone's avatar if it is offensive (hate speech, profanity, or nudity), but it doesn't sound like this is the kind of case you're describing. The only other time a moderator will take action on someone's avatar is if they're impersonating another user. This is a very narrow set of instances where we need to be worried about other people's avatars, so please just let this slide.

Comment: +1 for the _"Pretty girls can be nerds too"_ I never meant to decline that (though rare in the real world ;-P ...)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I feel completely misunderstood. I even wanted to speak against the sexist view. I've just noticed behavior based on that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Trust me, I know a few IRL that fit that description.

Answer (score 10):

Many male members of this community use male pictures as avatars. Similarly, female avatars are allowed.

That being said, please reconsider how we, as the female members of the community will feel when we read such posts. A post should focus on **content**.

Judge posts by quality, not looks of the author. If I judge by quality, this question completely fails to meet any standards of SE, though it may be suitable for Y-Answers forum.

Comment: Well I mentioned we should focus on content! And I pretty much go along with _"as the female members of the community will feel"_. That's a major point, how we should change to think about judging questions.

Comment: Simple @πάνταῥεῖ. Ignore the avatar, answer the question. (Or close it, downvote it, edit it ... whatever the question deserves)

Comment: @Bart Yes I agree. upvoted..

Comment: Then ban all human avatars, male and female, if you want to change to think about judging questions @πάντα

Comment: I think we should ban ducks and blue footed boobies as avatars!!! :D

Comment: @TGMCians, please change your avatar. I am unable to judge the quality of your comment because of your avatar :P

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Oh no please :)

Comment: @bluefeet Yes !!/ban ducks!! :D

Comment: @Bart Of course I'm going to ignore the avatar. You've seemingly missed my concerns.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I don't want to ban them. Pretty girls should be able to show up as pretty they can be, or everyone else should like to show up as they want! I just have that feeling that some users misuse that rights (with a sexist intention).

Comment: And there's practically nothing you can do about that if that's the case @πάνταῥεῖ. If we're not talking offensive avatars or clear impersonations (and not just an avatar that isn't you) then there's nothing to do but judge the content.

Answer (score 9):

If pretty girls are allowed to use pretty girls as avatar, so are other users.

Comment: That might consolidate as the _"real question"_!